# Running mongoDB on ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, meteor

I'm trying to run mongodb on my ubuntu :

calling `sudo service mongodb start` tells me that mongo is already running.

But when i run the command `mongo` or `mongod` i get the error :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The weird thing is that I have a meteor application already using this mongoDB, and it is working correctly. My only problem is that i want to view/access the data from outside meteor and from a mongo client.

Thanks.

`ps aux | grep mongo` gives me :

```
mongodb  27835  1.0  1.4 204936 14644 ?        Ssl  12:59   1:13 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
root     30838  0.0  0.0   4344   836 pts/0    S+   14:53   0:00 grep --color=auto mongo
```

Comment: So are you lay down meteor app when you try start mongodb instance?

Comment: I don't know if i understood you well, but this error happens regardless if my meteor app is running or not.

Comment: Show me "ps aux | grep mongo"

Comment: i put the result in my question

Comment: are you running the command `meteor mongo` in the project directory while meteor is running?

Comment: No i'm deploying the meteor app as a bundle, meteor is not installed on this machine.
@Denis, if meteor is running why the command `mongo` is not working? anything in config to change ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Looks like an old version of Boost was used to compile Mongo. Try  executing

export LC_ALL=C

first before starting mongo shell

Comment: That was it exactly, can you explain to me please what happened ? what is Boost ?

Comment: Boost is C++ library used by MongoDB. Versions older than 1.4.7 had an issue with locales other than C in certain configurations. See https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/4688 for more information.

Comment: You could add the variable definition  LC_ALL=C to /etc/enviroment